# Javascript validate checkboxes with array values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Plot**
I have some dynamic js validations that first scan for all fields in a step (HTMLElement). Basically I populate `checkbox_groups` with all the names and then check if at least one is checked. This works good except a certain situation.

**Problem**
I have some dynamic checkboxes that have names like: `person[1]`, `person[2]`, `person[3]`. Because the id is specified my error `<p>` appears under each checkbox instead of only the last checkboxes as intended. Basically all I want is to find a way to modify this script so in this scenario the error message to appear only after the last checkbox.

**Code**

```
/**
 * Validate step checkboxes
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 *
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function validate_step_checkboxes(step) {
    var checkbox_groups = [];
    var errors = [];
    var error = false;

    $.each(step.find('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"]'), function () {
        var myname = this.name;
        if ($.inArray(myname, checkbox_groups) < 0) {
            checkbox_groups.push(myname);
        }
    });

    console.log('groups');
    console.log(checkbox_groups);

    // Check if there is a checkbox selected for each checkbox group
    for (i = 0; i < checkbox_groups.length; i++) {
        if (step.find('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"]:checked').length <= 0) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"][name="' + checkbox_groups[i] + '"]').last().closest('.checkbox-label').after('<p class="input-error">Please select one option.</p>');
            errors[checkbox_groups[i]] = 'Field required';
            error = true;
        }
    }
    return !error;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="primary-table hidden-xs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>X/th>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>&emsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[1]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[2]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[3]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[4]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: We really need to see a minimal chunk of your HTML; I've been playing around with your code but I'm having to guess (and work) to come up with what your HTML might look like.  Can you add a *minimal* snippet that helps demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I added the table where this happens, basically I get the error message after every .checkbox-label intead of only the last one, because it sees all names as unique due to the [1], [2], [3], instead of detecting only person. Updated the post.

Comment: Well ... they are unique.  Your HTML uses unique names, so they're all independent; but the JS assumes they're all part of a single set.  Is there a reason you're using unique names?  It is perfectly valid to group checkboxes in a set with the same name, eg `person[]` (or `people[]`).

Comment: Should I maybe simply use person[] and add their id's into the value attribute ? I will try it out and do some regression testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, the HTML defines each individual checkbox as part of a unique set (eg `person[1]`).  But the Javascript expects those to be *groups* of checkboxes ...

There is nothing wrong with using a checkbox name like `person`, you can still have 10 checkboxes with that name and check as many or as few as you like.  To make things easier on the backend it is common to use a name like `person[]`, so you get an array of values.  In this case since you're selecting multiple persons maybe `people[]` is an appropriate name.

If you really need unique `name`s for each checkbox for some reason, the only way I can think of to get the JS to treat them as part of a single group is to strip off the `[1]` part to find the common "base" name.  This does not seem like a good idea though, fragile and hacky.  I've included a working example below, but I wouldn't recommend using this.

Maybe a better option would be to treat the block of HTML as the semantic group?  So the input `name` isn't relevant, you're just looking for something checked inside that `<div>` (or maybe `<table>` in your case)?  But again this doesn't feel like a good option, we're circumventing the built in properties that are supposed to do exactly this - the `name` specifies how inputs are grouped.

```js
/**
 * Validate step checkboxes
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 *
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function validate_step_checkboxes(step) {
    var checkbox_groups = [];
    var errors = [];
    var error = false;

    $.each(step.find('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"]'), function () {
        var myname = this.name;
        
        // Check if this name includes [1], etc
        if (myname.match(/\[\d\]/)) {
            // It does, let's get the "base name" without [1]
            myname = myname.replace(/\[\d\]/, '');
            console.log('stripped', myname);
        } 
        if ($.inArray(myname, checkbox_groups) < 0) {
            checkbox_groups.push(myname);
        }
    });

    console.log('groups');
    console.dir(checkbox_groups);

    // Check if there is a checkbox selected for each checkbox group
    for (i = 0; i < checkbox_groups.length; i++) {
        if (step.find('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"]:checked').length <= 0) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"][data-required="1"][name^="' + checkbox_groups[i] + '"]').last().closest('.checkbox-label').after('<p class="input-error">Please select one option.</p>');
            errors[checkbox_groups[i]] = 'Field required';
            error = true;
        }
    }
    
    console.log('errors:');
    console.dir(errors);
    return !error;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    let $step1 = $('.primary-table');
    let valid = validate_step_checkboxes($step1);
    console.log('valid:', valid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="primary-table hidden-xs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>X/<th>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>x</th>
            <th>&emsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[1]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[2]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[3]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="checkbox-label">Test PErson
                <input name="person[4]" type="checkbox" data-required="1">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td><a href="h#">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```